# Preloading Ext JS & custom JavaScript files at application boot time

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, preload

I'm creating an intranet application, the UI of which premoninently uses Ext JS 4.1.1

I have created several custom javascript classes extending Ext JS controls and other code for UI, validation, communication, etc.

Given that my code is not very huge and that my application will be deployed in a controlled & well known environment I'd ideally like to load all .js files upfront at the time of application invokation (boot). I'd like to know an approach to achieve this, mostly from within the relm of Ext JS.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is something really usual. Take a look at the deployment section to know how to use the Sencha SDK to create one file containing all your custom javascript classes which extend extjs component [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started-section-3)

I hope it is useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

As of this month Sencha (beta) released a revamped build tool. Actually, it is a complete rewrite in Java (I believe). `Sencha Cmd` is the name, and it is all that the predecessor should have been!

Compile times have been crunched to maybe a 10th of its predecessor and packages/builds are now configured using a powerful command processor.

Integration into other build frameworks and CI servers is now a top priority and achieved by integrating the tool with ANT.

I just spent the past hours to migrate a project from the old `Sencha SDK Tools` to the new `Sencha Cmd`. I particularly love the new compiler.

Documentation is already pretty good.

- [Blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/all-new-sencha-cmd/) that introduced `Sencha Cmd`
- [Official SDK documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command) - there is a total of 10 articles on the subject, don't miss them, particularly the
- [Compiler documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_compiler)

For smaller projects that follow the standard (single-page) pattern suggested by Sencha, there is actually a range of higher-level commands that manage the entire application creation and build process.

Furthermore, Sencha has now a pattern in place for [multi-page applications](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_app_multi).

And you can always use the compiler directly and implement your own build process on top of it. That's what we did in our project.

Answer (score 0):

There is one class called [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader)

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a server-side question than an Ext JS question. You want to include all your pages up-front? Get a JavaScript compressor to concatenate your files together, minify the whole pack, and add a `<script>` tag to every page in your web app.

I also work on an intranet web app that heavily uses Ext JS (both 3 and 4), but we have quite a large codebase. Since we use Tomcat, we have a Java class that includes standard files on each page, plus any file groups or individual files we need for that page. Something like that might work for you as well.

You can use `Ext.Loader` for dynamic loading when you need it, but that doesn't sounds like what you're looking for. Still an option though, should your codebase expand and you need a better solution.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comments, my original answer failed to address the [Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/). I felt it would be more beneficial to make my response part of my revised answer.

While this task may be exactly what the Sencha SDK was designed for, I feel that the product is not yet mature enough for production environments. At the time of writing, the current version is 2.0.0 Beta 3. Beta, meaning it's still under development, and it shows. Documentation is practically non-existent and the official forums are full of topics claiming the product simply does not work. At this point, it's nothing more than a toy to be played with. The most helpful document I've seen is [Sencha SDK Tools 2.0 and ExtJS4: The Missing Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_yrwYiRTeExJiSYDhhPV75UEo8HUyl_RDq0JzxIRwwk/edit?pli=1), and the author even ends with "The SDK Tools need a lot of work."

When I'm choosing a product for a production environment, I want something stable, something reliable, something with good documentation, something with quality support. The Sencha SDK Tools are none of those things. Yet.

Comment: Not sure how one can talk about Ext4, minification, Ext.Loader and not mention the Sencha SDK? The OP is describing a best-fit scenario for using the Sencha SDK to create a minified single-file javascript file. Sorry, downvoted for not pointing out the obvious solution.

Comment: I removed the downvote. However, I don't agree with your conclusion that the Sencha SDK Tools are 'nothing more than a toy to be played with'. **We are currently using the tool successfully in our build process**, and I assume that many others do as well. 
Yes, the docs could be improved, and getting a working setup might not be as fail-proof as it should be. 
With every tool there is a learning process involved. If you are prepared to do the required reading and accept that the initial setup might be more involving than running two commands from the command line, I am sure you get it to work.

Comment: Looking back on it, that "toy" remark is unnecessary. I know that many groups are using it, and I'm glad that it's working for you. But the point I was trying to make is that the tools are still subject to quite a bit of change, and at this point may not be worth the investment as opposed to finding an existing tool that works more or less out-of-the-box.

Comment: Sencha's SDK tools actually use yuicompressor for minification - so no surprises or beta stuff here. The SDK tools add two important features though: (1) determine dependencies and create a list of required javascript files  (2) support for removing debug code from the production build (marked with //<debug> .. //</debug>).

Comment: Ahh, that's what the //<debug> statements are for. I've seen them scattered throughout the Ext JS source but I didn't know they were for automated code removal. Interesting.